# Executing the code returned by `sys.on.exit()`, why does `eval(sys.on.exit())` not work?

Tags: r

I'm using `on.exit()` function to ensure execution of clean up code after a section that can fail. In the simplest case, it is

```
fun1 = function(){
    # Turn on clean up on exit
    on.exit({
        message('Cleaning Up')
    })
    message('Function finishes')
}

fun1()

# Function finishes
# Cleaning Up
```

Sometimes, I want to run the clean up code before the function finishes.
I do this by getting the code previously provided to `on.exit` via `sys.on.exit` and applying function `eval` to it.

```
fun2 = function(){
    # Turn on clean up on exit
    on.exit({
        message('Cleaning Up')
    })

    # Cleaning up before function ends
    tmp = sys.on.exit()
    eval(tmp)
    # Turn off clean up on exit
    on.exit()

    message('Function finishes')
}
fun2()

# Cleaning Up
# Function finishes
```

However, if do not use the intermediate variable `tmp` and simplify the code to `eval(sys.on.exit())` it does not clean up.

```
fun3 = function(){
    # Turn on the clean up on exit
    on.exit({
        message('Cleaning Up')
    })

    # Cleaning up before function ends
    eval(sys.on.exit())
    # Turn off the clean up on exit
    on.exit()

    message('Function finishes')
}
fun3()

# Function finishes
```

Can someone explain why `tmp=sys.on.exit();eval(tmp)` works while `eval(sys.on.exit())` does not?

Comment: I think what's going on is that since parameters in R are promises, they aren't evaluated till they are needed and at that point the `eval()` function has created a new context that may have a different `on.exit`? Just a guess. It's a very interesting question.

Comment: @MrFlick, that's an interesting idea. Thank you.
Quote: "`sys.on.exit()` returns the expression stored for use by `on.exit` in the function currently being evaluated".

Comment: @MrFlick, I think your comment deserves to be an answer.

Comment: I'm not convinced I'm right. I tried calling another function that had an on.exit but it didn't find that one either. The C source is straightforward but there is something about the call stack that I'm just missing I think.